# SQL user not associated with a trusted connection

Tags: sql-server-2005

I just set up a new server with SQL Server Express 2005, and I want to connect remotely.

1. I set both Windows and SQL logins.
2. I modified so both local and remote connections are allowed.
3. I restarted the server.
4. Windows firewall is not connected; I have an external firewall with a hole at port 1443.
5. The user account is active and there is no password policy or forcing to change on next login (etc).

If I even try to connect using this username locally on the server using 'File | Connect to object explorer', I get the same message: that the user is not associated with a trusted connection.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the user as a SQL login?

Comment: yes I did that ofcourse :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Microsoft KB (http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;914277)for connecting remotely using SQL Express 2005. I would say go through the exact steps as described just one more time to make sure nothing has been left out. Good luck and I hope it helps!